# Permitir certo ID logado apenas

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

O meu site salva no banco de dados o ID do usuário, daí ele quando logado, fica com o ID. Queria conseguir algum tipo de código que fizesse a seguinte tarefa:

Quando usuário logado com ID "x" no site e estiver passando por páginas, daí em certa página fazer com que ele não tenha permissão de acessar essa certa página, e quando acessar ser redirecionado para outra, informando que ele não tem permissão. Somente usuários que conter por exemplo no arquivo permitido.txt (ou PHP), ter essas permissões...

Eu até tenho algo parecido mais ele só funciona ao contrário que quero, ou seja, ao invés dele permitir o ID ele o bloqueia, queria algo ao contrário.. Abaixo está oque eu tenho:

```
}
    }else{
        header('Location: ?type=status');
    }
}

if($user->id =="1000012034731" || $user->id =="4"){
    echo "Tenha um bom dia! Você está bloqueado...!!";
    echo "<br>";
    echo " Nossa equipe detectou algo errado em sua conta.";
    exit;
}

if(isset($_POST['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: index.php?i=Logout Success..!! ');
}
?>
```

Obs.: Já tentei mudar os sinais de "==" para diferente, mais mesmo assim não deu..

Comment: Tentei formatar seu código da melhor forma possível, mas o mesmo está incompleto. Acredito que na hora de copiar, você selecionou apenas uma parte dele. Tem como [edit] a pergunta e adicionar o código completo? E o que acontece se o usuário de `id` 1000012034731 ou 4 entrar na página?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Você poderia citar + ou - como ficaria sua sugestão? Obrigado;

Comment: Olá, @Anderson Carlos Woss No caso esses seriam os IDs dos usuários que não são permitidos de acessar tal pagina. Eu queria o contrário, ao inves de banir, ele apenas autoriza o acesso daqueles IDs. Obs.: Os IDs acima citados, são apenas um exemplo. Queria que ficasse na verdade no lugar do ID apenas chamasse um arquivo .txt com os IDs permitidos. Obrigado;